# gdal_proximity generates zeros on large raster files

Tags: distance, gdal

I have a raster (`fcc.tif`) of forest (value 1) and deforested pixels (value 0) with no data values (255) having a resolution of 30m for Papua New Guinea. This is a large raster with 60459 x 40811 pixels.

I try to use gdal_proximity.py (GDAL version 2.1.2) to compute the distance (in m) to the deforested pixels. I am using the following command:

```
gdal_proximity.py fcc.tif dist_defor.tif -values 0 -ot UInt32 -distunits GEO -use_input_nodata YES -nodata 4294967295
```

Computation is working fine for most of the region but produces incorrect zeros values on a large area having a kind of disk shape (marked in red on the following figure).

[Distance to deforestation in Papua New Guinea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7zqS.jpg)

In this area, deforested pixels are present, but they seem not to be taken into account for computing distances.

The raster `fcc.tif` is available [here](https://nextcloud.fraisedesbois.net/index.php/s/pTVHRflJrL2yy4z)

Answer (score 1):

This was due to an integer overflow that occurred during distance computation on large datasets. Issue has been addressed per https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/7102. Thanks to the developers and maintainer of GDAL who resolved this issue.